# How do I fix this memory leak with an overloaded operator?

Tags: c++, matrix, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have been extending the `Matrix` class from the "operator overloading" section of the [C++ Super-FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op). I ran my program through `Valgrind`:

```
==6208== 48 (16 direct, 32 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 6
==6208==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6208==    by 0x108E98: Matrix::operator*(Matrix&) (in /home/l/a.out)
==6208==    by 0x1090BA: main (in /home/l/a.out)
==6208== 
==6208== 48 (16 direct, 32 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 6
==6208==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6208==    by 0x108FC2: Matrix::transpose() const (in /home/l/a.out)
==6208==    by 0x108EC2: Matrix::operator*(Matrix&) (in /home/l/a.out)
==6208==    by 0x1090BA: main (in /home/l/a.out)
```

I can see that the issue is in `operator*`. My implementation for this operator is as follows:

```
Matrix &Matrix::operator*(Matrix &m) {
    auto result = new Matrix(rows_, m.cols_);
    auto &mTranspose = m.transpose();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < rows_; ++i) {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < m.cols_; ++j) {
            result->data_[i][j] = std::inner_product(data_[i], data_[i] + cols_, mTranspose.data_[j], 0);
        }
    }
    return *result;
}
```

I call the operator using patterns like what is shown in the below sample `main()`:

```
int main() {
    Matrix m(2,2);
    Matrix n(2,2);

    auto &a = m * n; // pattern A
    auto * b = &(m*n); // pattern B
```

The reason I allocate the object on the heap in the operator is because I need the result of the `Matrix` multiply to persist after the multiplication is done; elsewhere in my program I use a loop where I need to keep track of previous `Matrix` multiplies.

How do I fix this memory leak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare a local variable, and return it.

```
Matrix result(rows_, m.cols_);
// ....
return result;
```

When you use it, just use it like you do with multiplies for real numbers.

```
auto a = m * n;    // Not a reference
auto b = m * n;    // Not a pointer
```

Depending on what `m.transpose()` returns, the transpose might need to be `auto mTranspose = m.transpose();` (i.e., not a reference).